# Microsoft TPL (Task parallel library) vs Intel TBB (Threading Building Block)

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tbb

My question is, as the title says :
On a general level (ease of usage, degree of control over what happens, etc) which one would you recommend for a small parallel program ? Microsoft's TPL or Intel's TBB ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What language are we talking about? TPL is a .net 4 library, TBB a C++ one. They serve different purposes as well.

Comment: I am actually free to chose the programming language I want. But i prefer working with .NET/C# so I guess I don`t have much of a choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really easy to answer this. TBB is a C++ template library, while TPL is a .NET library. Assuming you can choose whichever language you like, they both offer similar general-purpose parallel constructs, mainly:

- parallel loops: `Parallel.For` in TPL and `parallel_for` in TBB
- parallel tasks: `Task` in TPL and `tbb:task` in TBB
- various concurrent collections
- other parallel patterns e.g. `parallel_reduce` in TBB which can be emulated with plinq in TPL

But again, depending on the language you choose you don't really have a choice between the two.

Comment: And the choice of langauge should e governed by other factors ;)